# How can i draw a sudoku box and some other shapes in comments of vs code? Is there any extension for that

Tags: visual-studio-code

**I want to draw sudoku box in the multiple line comment in python. I want it to look like box not 2-D array**

Comment: what does that look like (**example**)

Comment: Just like sudoku box that we see on paper and mobile

Comment: you are unable to show us an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/NwkLGo67KdA1ikK89. Look at this link i want to construct a sudoku table looks like that not 2-D list

Comment: use the box characters, available in every font

Comment: Could you share me how to use that

Comment: just like you would use `+-` use the Char Map application of your OS to look up the codes of the box characters you like to use, single lines, double lines, thin/think lines, or combination

Comment: I want to draw that box in the comment not in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

There are [ASCII codes](https://gist.github.com/dsample/79a97f38bf956f37a0f99ace9df367b9) for this purpose. Here are all the characters you need for a sudoku box, simply copy and paste it into your comment and extend it for your needs:

```
┌───┬───┐
│   │   │
├───┼───┤
│   │   │
└───┴───┘
```

For more sophisticated designs there is a website called [ASCIIFlow](https://asciiflow.com/), which enables you to visually draw boxes with your mouse and then export it to a text document.